# Can I parameterize OAuth options for my users?

Tags: .net, oauth

I want to present a list of mobile apps that my users can choose to grant OAuth access to.

I want to parameterize this list in my database, so I can easily add new mobile apps to the list by adding that app's unique details to my database table.  I expect the parameters will include the various OAuth URLs needed, the unique ApplicationID I got when I registered with them, and so on.  When the member clicks on one from my list, it presents the appropriate prompts to collect their username/password, etc. for that app.

Can I make a generic parameterized OAuth authorization system like this?  Or will each mobile app require me to do unique custom coding to set up the user's authorization?

I had heard we'd need to install a unique DLL on my Windows web server, for each mobile app maker, just to do OAuth.  (Not the actual data-calls, just establishing the OAuth.  I know that many app makers publish .NET DLLs to simplify the data calls...I'm not talking about that.)

Possible?  Can anyone point me to documentation if it is possible?

Many thanks,
- Tom